# Python: Time complexity of min() function inside for loop

Tags: python, loops, time-complexity, big-o, min

I'm calculating time complexities of algorithms and I assumed both code below to have time complexities of O(n^2)
However my books says first code is O(n^2) and second one is O(n). I don't understand why. Both are using min/max, so whats the difference?
Code 1:

```
def sum(l, n):

for i in range(1, n - 1):
    x = min(l[0:i])
    y = min(l[i:num])
return x+y
```

Code 2:

```
def sum(a, n):
r = [0] * n
l = [0] * n
min_el = a[0]

for i in range(n):
    min_el = min(min_el, a[i])
    l[i] = min_el


print(min_el)
```

Comment: Code 1 makes no sense.  You're calculating new `x`/`y` values on each iteration of the loop, overwriting the values from the previous iteration.  Only the final iteration has any effect on the returned value; all the previous iterations were simply wasted work.

Comment: I'll give you a hint...The `min` function can either take an iterable (e.g. `min([1, 2, 3, ... n])`) or individual values (e.g. `min(1, 2)`). Consider the different time complexities for each of these cases.

Comment: I see what you mean, I thought of it too, but I thought min()/max() functions were always O(n)? I had no clue time complexities could differ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first block of code the block of code runs the min function over the whole array, which takes O(n) time. Now considering it is in a loop of length n then the total time is O(n^2)

Looking at the 2nd block of code. Note that the min function is only comparing 2 values, which is arguably O(1). Now considering that it is in a loop of length n. The total time is simply the summation of O(n+n+n), which is equal to O(n)

Comment: Do you have any source which could elaborate how time complexities differ based on what they're comparing cuz I thought these functions were always O(n)

Comment: I suggest you check any video that talks about the big O notation. The channel of freeCodeCamp had some nice resources if you have the time. But in simple terms, it is only O(n) if it is looking at n number of values. If min has a fixed value (2 in this case for the 2nd code) then its O(1) running time.

Comment: Alright, thanks, I get it now

Answer (score 0):

In the first code, it gives an array to the min() function, and this O(n) time complexity because it checks all elements in the array, in the second code, min() functions only compare two values and it takes O(1)